# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context AVAudioSession

Tags: swift, avaudiosession

I'm trying to add notification observer to detect when headphones are removed and the music stop playing. I followed [Audio Session](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/responding_to_audio_session_route_changes). I'm trying to search Swift 4.2 syntax, changed some things from the original code from Apple but I still get this error:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

What am I doing wrong? Let me know if I need to add more code

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(audioRouteChanged), name: .AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification, object: nil)
    //Error this line: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

}

@objc func audioRouteChanged(notification: Notification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
    guard let reason = userInfo[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? Int else { return }

    if reason == AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.hashValue {
        // headphones plugged out
        // continue playback or change the play/pause icon
        playPauseButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play"), for: .normal)
        miniPlayPauseButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a leading `.` in `.AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification`. Deleting that will solve the error.

Comment: yep, I fixed it, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the dot before AVAudioSession  `name: .AVAudioSession.routeChangeNotification`